# file.endswith returns zip folder and file inside it

Tags: python, os.path

I am trying to append a list with absolute paths to a file, the file is a zip folder with `.gz` extension, but since the file inside zip folder has also `.gz` extension, this returns both. How can I change my code to return only paths to zip folder and not the files inside it as well? Thanks!

```
labels = []

for path, currentDirectory, files in os.walk(os.path.join(dir, 'labels/')):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.gz'):
            masks = Path(path + '/' + file)
            labels.append(masks)
```

Comment: Python doesn't iterate the contents of zip files automatically; it shouldn't be seeing anything inside the zip file. Are you sure you didn't *extract* the zip file to make a folder in the same directory? `os.walk` explores a directory tree *recursively*; if you extract the zip file (making *real*, not zipped, folders), `os.walk` will process it.

Comment: I am positive I have files not extracted, it basically returns a ```._foo.nii.gz``` and a ```foo.nii.gz```. 

OK So it's the not file, you are right. Still I get the two names. :/

Comment: Okay, first off, you need to get your terminology straight. gzipped files aren't folders. They're not even logical folders (gzip is a compression format; archiving multiple files together is handled by other tooling, e.g. tarballs). Zip files are different (and combined archiving and compression in one thing). In any event, if you're on a UNIX-like system, I strongly recommend you open a command line, `cd` to the `labels` folder you're processing, and run `find . -name '*.nii.gz'`; I strongly suspect `find` will locate both such files.

Comment: I see .. It did return both, yes!

Comment: Yep. So your problem's not a Python problem, it's a "things are on your file system that you don't want to be there"; `find` definitely won't look inside compressed or archive files, it's just iterating the raw file system entries. Python's doing exactly what you asked, same as `find`. :-)

Comment: Yea it does make sense now, thanks for the answer!